# Get current instance id within EB worker - BOTO Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto

Within an EB worker on AWS I would like to identify the instance that the code is running on.
I'm using Boto and Python.
I know I can list all the instances but how can I know the instance that this worker is running on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using or depending on the boto wouldn't help. The more easier way is to depend on the `EC2 Meta-Data`

You can do a curl or perform http-get from your instance to the URL - `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` and get the data.

To fetch Instance ID - perform a curl to `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

The other details you can get from Meta-Data are

```
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
kernel-id
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
network/
placement/
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

More Info - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Boto might still be useful.  The ``boto.utils`` module provides a function called ``get_instance_metadata`` that retrieves the data from the metadata service.  It also handles retries if the server doesn't respond initially.